# Automatically cast an active record child class on initialisation in its parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an Subscription model which then has child class SubscriptionCleaning and a subscription has a a subscription_type_id where 1 is SubscriptionCleaning. I also have a SubscriptionType model.

What i want to happen is when i do for example

`Subscription.find(100)`
which has a subscription type id of 1

for it to be automatically cast SubscriptionCleaning

i've tried doing an initialise method on my subscription class

```
after_initialize :my_test
#
def my_test
    if self.subscription_type_id.present?
        self.becomes!('SubscriptionCleaning'.constantize)
    end
end
```

this errors with NoMethodError: undefined method `type=' for

I can do it line by line in console and it returns fine but not as an initialisation for a subscription

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on Single table inheritance, which is resolved by the `type` column. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance

**UPDATE:**

The link isn't very useful. Short description, you can remove your `subscription_type_id` column and add a `type` column. If you create a model `SubscriptionCleaning < Subscription` it will be persisted in the same column as the `Subscription` model and you get the "type casting" out of the box.